# Is there a utility that can identify the class of SD card / microSD card?

Tags: sd-card, micro-sd-card

Is there a utility, for Windows 7 64-bit preferably, that can tell me the type of SD card or microSD card that has been inserted Class 4, class 6, etc.

Freeware is preferred, but I am willing to hear about other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this utility ([H2testw](http://mympx.org/Downloads/p13_sectionid/2/p13_fileid/13)) to determine the class of your SD card. If the test result is "n MB/secs", then its class is "n".

Normally, SD cards are Class 2 unless it is specified on it.